# Magento 2 Unit test for exception

Tags: exception, testing, magento2.2, unit-tests, phpunit

Got a basic question about handling Exceptions in Magento 2. I'm currently on Magento 2.2 with PHPUnit 6.2.4. I would like to write a test for a CouldNotSaveException.

Got the following code example

```
try {
    $this->customerDataResource->save($customerDataObject);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new CouldNotSaveException(new Phrase(
        'Unable to save customer with ID '. $customerData->getCustomerId()
    ));
}
```

Currently got the following usage from PHPUnit documentation

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest.php

```
/**
* Test save() method when exception is thrown
*/
public function testSaveException()
{
    $this->expectException(CouldNotSaveException::class);
}
```

I'm mocking my objects using the `createMock()` method. Don't really know how to write the rest of the code.

If someone could help me out that would be great.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For an example your code looks like this:

```
class CustomerService
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerDataResource
     */
    private $customerDataResource;

    public function __construct(CustomerDataResource $customerDataResource)
    {
        $this->customerDataResource = $customerDataResource;
    }

    public function save(DataObject $customerDataObject)
    {
        try {
            $this->customerDataResource->save($customerDataObject);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(new Phrase(
                'Unable to save customer with ID '. $customerDataObject->getCustomerId()
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

And your test method might look something like this:

```
/**
 * @expectedException CouldNotSaveException
 * @expectedExceptionMessage Unable to save customer with ID 1
 */
public function testSave()
{
    $customerDTO = new DataObject();
    $customerDTO->setCustomerId(1);

    // create service mock, which will throw an exception
    $customerDataResource = $this->getMockBuilder(CustomerDataResource::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $customerService = new CustomerService($customerDataResource);

    $customerDataResource->method('save')
        ->willThrowException(new CouldNotSaveException('Unable to save customer with ID ' . $customerDTO->getCustomerId()));

    $customerService->save($customerDTO);
}
```

As you can see, the test method is pretty simple and uses PHPUnit annotations to provide assertions for exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

**After** calling `$this->expectException()` run the code that throws an exception, i.e. `$testSubject->save()`. That's it. If the exception has not been thrown at the end of the test, the test fails,